# Get template author and license

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Based on this sample code, on Joomla 3.9.5

```php
$app            = JFactory::getApplication();
$getTemplateId  = $app->getTemplate('template')->id;
```

I'm trying to get template author and license from the XML/SQLdb

```php
$app                = JFactory::getApplication();
$getTemplateAuthor  = $app->getTemplate('template')->author;
$getTemplateLicense = $app->getTemplate('template')->license;
```

This of course doesn't work so I would be happy with any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the database in phpMyAdmin, I came up with this solution

```php
// get app
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
// get template
$templateName = $app->getTemplate();
// hook Joomla Database API
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// set query
$db->setQuery("SELECT manifest_cache FROM #__extensions where `type` = 'template' AND `element` = '".$templateName."'");
// extract the manifest_cache column
$templateMETA = $db->loadObject()->manifest_cache; 
// decode JSON and build an object
$templateMETA = json_decode( $templateMETA );
// set author&license
$author = $templateMETA->author;
$license = $templateMETA->license;
```

The `manifest_cache` holds the template and possibly any Joomla extension meta information.

Hope this helps someone.